# How do I access particular div based on the index of the template in knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a template which gets repeated in the html page each time I click on the ADD button. I want to access the input with id `selectListGroup` based on a particular index.
For eg: if the user is on the 2nd template, I want to disable `selectListGroup` only for the 2nd template.

```
<script type="text/html" id="attributeTemplate">
    <div class="margin_top10"> </div>
    <div class="oj-flex cls_main_template" data-bind="attr: {index:$index()}">
        <div class="oj-flex-items-pad oj-sm-1 alignCenter " > + </div>
        <div class="oj-flex-items-pad oj-sm-11 " >
            <div class="oj-padding  oj-panel-alt2" style="border:1px solid #e8e8e8;border-radius:5px;">
                <div class="oj-flex">
                    <div class="oj-sm-4">
                        <div class="padding10">
                            <select id="selectListCondition" data-bind="ojComponent: {component: 'ojSelect',
                                                             optionChange:function(event,ui){$parent.Onchg_Condition(event, ui, $index())},
                                                             rootAttributes: {style:'max-width:10em'}}">
                                <option value="AND">AND</option>
                                <option value="OR">OR</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="oj-sm-4"></div>
                    <div class="oj-sm-4">
                        <div class="padding10 floatRight"><button class="margin-left3 deleteBtn"  data-bind="click:function(event, ui) {$parent.btnDeleteConditionClick(event, ui, $element, $index());}, ojComponent: {component: 'ojButton', label: 'Delete Condition'}"> </button> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="oj-flex oj-panel-alt1" style="border:1px solid #e8e8e8; border-radius:5px;">
                    <div id="entityDiv" class="floatLeft padding10 oj-invalid cls_query_input">
                        <select id="selectListEntity" data-bind="ojComponent:
                                             {component: 'ojSelect',
                                              options:$parent.arr_entities,
                                              optionChange:function(event,ui){$parent.Onchg_Entity(event, ui, $index())},
                                              placeholder: $parent.emptyPlaceholder() ? '' : 'Select Entity',
                                             rootAttributes: {style:'max-width:10em'}}">
                            <option value="Item">Item</option>
                            <option value="Catalog">Catalog</option>
                            <option value="EFF">EFF</option>
                            <option value="Structure">Structure</option>
                            <option value="Relationship">Relationship</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="floatLeft padding10 cls_query_input" style="width:22%">    
                        <input id="selectListGroup" disable
                               data-bind="ojComponent: {component: 'ojSelect',
                                    placeholder: $parent.emptyPlaceholder() ? '' :'Select Group',
                                    options:$parent.arr_groups,
                                    optionChange:$parent.Onchg_Groups,
                                    rootAttributes: {style:'max-width:25em'}}"/>

                    </div>
                    <div class="floatLeft padding10 cls_query_input" style="width:20%">
                        <select id="selectListAttribute" data-bind="ojComponent:
                                                     {component: 'ojSelect',
                                                      optionChange: $parent.Onchg_Attribute,
                                                      options: $parent.arr_attributes,
                                                     placeholder: $parent.emptyPlaceholder() ? '' : 'Select Attribute',
                                                     rootAttributes: {style:'max-width:25em'}}">

                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="floatLeft padding10 cls_query_input">
                        <select id="selectListOperator" data-bind="ojComponent:
                                                     {component: 'ojSelect',
                                                     optionChange:$parent.Onchg_Operator,
                                                     placeholder: $parent.emptyPlaceholder() ? '' : 'Select Operator',
                                                     rootAttributes: {style:'max-width:20em'}}">
                            <option value="equal">equal</option>
                            <option value="not_equal">not equal</option>
                            <option value="in">in</option>
                            <option value="not_in">not in</option>
                            <option value="less">less</option>
                            <option value="less_or_equal">less or equal</option>
                            <option value="greater">greater</option>
                            <option value="greater_or_equal">greater or equal</option>
                            <option value="between">between</option>
                            <option value="not_between">not between</option>
                            <option value="is_null">is null</option>
                            <option value="is_not_null">is not null</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="padding10 cls_query_input">
                        <div class="floatLeft" data-bind="if:$parent.showText">
                            <input class="cls_textInput" type=text data-bind="ojComponent: {component: 'ojInputText'}" 
                                   placeholder="Enter the attribute Value"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="floatLeft" data-bind="if:$parent.showNumber">
                            <input data-bind="ojComponent: {component: 'ojInputNumber',
                                                            value: $parent.numberAttrValue}" 
                                   placeholder="Enter the attribute Value"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="floatLeft" data-bind="if:$parent.showDate">
                            <input data-bind="ojComponent: {component: 'ojInputDate', 
                                                            value: $parent.dateAttrValue}" 
                                   placeholder="Enter the attribute Value"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="oj-messaging-inline-container" aria-live="polite" data-bind="if:$parent.showErrorMsg">
                        <div class="oj-message oj-message-error">
                            <span class="oj-component-icon oj-message-status-icon oj-message-error-icon" title="Error" role="img"></span>
                            <div class="oj-message-content">
                                <div class="oj-message-summary">Error</div>
                                <div class="oj-message-detail">
                                    <span data-bind="text:$parent.error_messageDetails"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

I have the following function which is called when the Entity dropdown changes for a particular template.

```
    self.Onchg_Entity = function (context, data, index) {

};
```

Based on the data, I want `selectListGroup` to be disabled for this particular index

Answer (score 0):

This is going to generate multiple controls with the same ID of `selectListGroup`, which is invalid HTML.

Make the ID dynamic using the `attr` binding:

`data-bind="attr: { id: 'selectListGroup' + someNumericVar() }"`

where `someNumericVar` is an auto-incrementing property in your view model based on the number of times you clicked Add.

Actually, it looks like you have a custom binding that has a `rootAttributes` property; use that instead of `attr`.

Comment: How do I access the attr value? How do I set it?